# Finding a Constant $c$ so that a given ODE has a solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> **Question.** Find the constant $c$ such that the following problem has a solution 
>   $$-u''=c ~\text{in}~(a,b)\\
> u'(a)=-1,~u'(b)=1$$

**My Attempt.** Integrating the given equation we have:$$u(x)=-c\frac{x^2}{2}+Ax+B;~~ ~ (A,B ~\text{are arbitrary constants.)}$$

Now from the boundary conditions: $$-ca+A=-1\\-cb+A=1$$

Finally Adding last two equations I get: $c=\frac{2A}{a+b}$

Here $A$ is arbitrary it means $c$ is also arbitrary...Is this right...?? Does every $c$ the given equation has a solution satisfying the boundary condition?If I am wrong Please tell me how to do this type of problem.....Please help..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Instead of adding, subtract the two equations obtained from the boundary condidtions.

Comment: Oh...you are right...!!!